# Numbers of bricks is not a multiple of replica count - glusterfs

Tags: mysql, replication, glusterfs

I have 10 servers and want to use all as storage so tried to create volume with following command but its throwing error

```
gluster volume create gv0 replica 3 server1:/data/brick1/gv0 server2:/data/brick1/gv0 server3:/data/brick1/gv0 server4:/data/brick1/gv0 server5:/data/brick1/gv0 server6:/data/brick1/gv0 server7:/data/brick1/gv0 server8:/data/brick1/gv0 server9:/data/brick1/gv0 server10:/data/brick1/gv0
```

and it throws error

```
Numbers of bricks is not a multiple of replica count
```

what's recommendation in this scenario?

it look like if i create with replica 2 it will succeed, so what would be difference in my scenario if i create volume with replica 2 or replica 3(i am assuming i will use 9 bricks here) on 10 brick?

In replica 2 with 10 brick scenario will i face split brain issue?

Answer (score 2):

To store 3 copies of everything, you need 3N disks.  10 is not a multiple of 3.

3 copies seems like overkill, especially if they are all in the same building -- that is subject to the same fire, flood, earthquake, hurricane, or whatever.  Or can you spread them out geographically?

Comment: What would be the impact if i create 9 bricks with replica 3? We have 10 servers and chances are we may shutdown multiple servers(randomly) on base of requirement and any 5 or 6 will be up at any time.

Comment: If you will be manually shutting down random servers, the problem _and_ solution is in manual rules and discipline.  What if they randomly shutdown all 3 servers in a replica set?  You would be hosed.  The rule has to be "Never shutdown more than N-1 servers at the same time.  (N=3, the replica number.)

Comment: if i add 10 servers as peer and create volume with mentioning 3 servers, on shutting of one of server replica set , will gluster include other available server automatically in replicaset?

Comment: If it must rebuild the data on that new disk, that could take time -- possibly longer than is acceptable.  Perhaps the Question should include more on why you are looking at this kind of redundancy -- low reliability?  flaky network?  other things?  There may be a different solution for the real goal.

Comment: This is an IOT based solution which connected to particular devices which collect data from solar/wind/grid, So we powerup machines as per requirement when we use solar then solar related servers are up and likewise. Sometime all could be up.